# export a removed file in SVN

Tags: svn

I would like to [export](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.8/svn.ref.svn.c.export.html) a removed file from a specific revision number for which I'm sure the file existed at that point:

```
svn export -r 40 /folder/my_file.py my_file.py
```

However, against my expectations, I get:

> svn: E155007: '/folder/my_file.py' is not a working copy

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should tell Subversion file what file you want to export. Therefore, the path `/folder/my_file.py` has to be an URL like `https://svn.example.com/repos/folder/my_file.py`.

Comment: @API you could also try adding peg revision if the file was renamed or moved: http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.8/svn.advanced.pegrevs.html